# Not sure how to setup entity for list

Tags: entity-framework

I have a user

```
public class UserEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public List<UserTokenEntity> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

that has a list of tokens and I'm not sure how to set it up so that the key to UserEntityId is not null when I generate the migration. This is my TokenEntity

```
public class UserTokenEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(512)]
    [Required]
    public string TokenHash { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required]
    public string Device { get; set; }
}
```

when I add a migration for these entities a UserEntity_Id is created for the database on the token entity but it is a `nullable int` and I want `nullable` to be `false`

here is the migration generated

```
 public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserTokenEntities",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    TokenHash = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 512),
                    Device = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserEntity_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserEntities", t => t.UserEntity_Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserEntity_Id);)
    }
```

does anyone know how to set up the token entity to get the `UserEntity_Id` to be `nullable: false` without manually changing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly define the relationship:

```
public class UserTokenEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(512)]
    [Required]
    public string TokenHash { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    [Required]
    public string Device { get; set; }

    public int UserEntityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserEntityId")]
    public UserEntity UserEntity { get; set; }

}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships